# Measuring length in Southeast Korea projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, length, measurements, south-korea

I have a GIS dataset currently projected in Web Mercator.

Is there an option for a more accurate segmentation length projection when I need accurate lengths in Southeast Korea?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application to make these measurements?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to re-project your data?
Check https://epsg.io/ for appropriate projections for your study area. For example, EPSG:5179 might work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version you're using, see if [Calculate Geometry Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm) tool is available. It can calculate the geodesic length of features.